# Error to search a location by googleMapsAutoComplete.. on react native?

Tags: react-native, google-places-autocomplete

When I search some place it brokes the app, here is the error:

> Device: (357:37) this.mapView.animateToLocation is not a function. (In
>   'this.mapView.animateToLocation({
>           latitude: loc.lat,
>           longitude: loc.lng
>         })', 'this.mapView.animateToLocation' is undefined)

Here is the Search Input:

```
<MapInput style = {{flex: 1, position : 'absolute'}} notifyChange={loc => this.getCoordsFromName(loc)} />
```

And here is the animation marker to the chosen location:

```
 goCoordsFromName(loc) {
    this.setState({
      region: {
        latitude: loc.lat,
        longitude: loc.lng,
      },
    });
  }

  getCoordsFromName(loc) { 
    this.goCoordsFromName(loc);
    this.mapView.animateToLocation({
      latitude: loc.lat,
      longitude: loc.lng,
    })
  }

  animateToLocation = location => {
    this.mapView.animateToRegion({
      latitude: location.latitude,
      longitude: location.longitude,
      latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
      longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
    });
  };
```

Here is the reference of the full code:

https://snack.expo.io/@matheus_cbrl/react-native-maps-autocomplete?session_id=snack-session-zEXHnaZSt&referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fmedium.com%2F%40mohammad.nicoll%2Freact-native-maps-with-autocomplete-e9c71e493974

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution, I did it:

**This:**

```
 goCoordsFromName(loc) {
    this.setState({
      region: {
        latitude: loc.lat,
        longitude: loc.lng,
      },
    });
  }

  getCoordsFromName(loc) { 
    this.goCoordsFromName(loc);
    this.mapView.animateToLocation({
      latitude: loc.lat,
      longitude: loc.lng,
    })
  }

  animateToLocation = location => {
    this.mapView.animateToRegion({
      latitude: location.latitude,
      longitude: location.longitude,
      latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
      longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
    });
  };
```

**to:**

```
  getCoordsFromName(loc) { 
     this.mapView.animateToRegion({
      ...this.state.region,
      latitude: loc.lat,
      longitude: loc.lng,
      latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
      longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
    });
    this.setState(prevState => {
      return {
        region: {
          ...prevState.region,
          latitude: loc.lat,
          longitude: loc.lng,
        },
      };
    });
  }
```